# Why does Tracker reactivity not kick in exactly half the time when using multiple computations in one Jasmine describe block?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-velocity, meteor-tracker, meteor-jasmine

When testing reactivity with Jasmine some Tracker computations started behaving in a very intriguing way: Exactly half the computations are reactive, the other half is not.

What I did to test this behaviour is the following:

```
//In a describe block
var foo = new ReactiveVar(false);

it('should react to the changes of foo (1)', function(done) {
  Tracker.autorun(function observeFoo(fooComputation) {
    var fooValue = foo.get();
    console.log('foo in its computation is', fooValue);
    if ( fooValue === true ) {
      fooComputation.stop();
      done();
    }
  });

  setTimeout(function setFoo() {
    foo.set(true);
  }, 100);
});
```

So basically:

1. Initialize a reactive `foo` to `false`.
2. Start tracking it, waiting for it to get to `true` so that the test is declared to be `done()`.
3. Use a timeout to `foo.set(true)` and thus resolve the test.
4. Stop this computation because it's not needed any more.

Now, let's do that very same thing with a different variable:

```
var foo = new ReactiveVar(false),
    bar = new ReactiveVar(false);

it('should react to the changes of foo (1)', function(done) { /* ... */ });

it('should react to the changes of bar (2)', function(done) {
  Tracker.autorun(function observeBar(barComputation) {
    var barValue = bar.get();
    console.log('bar in its computation is', barValue);
    if ( barValue === true ) {
      barComputation.stop();
      done();
    }
  });

  setTimeout(function setBar() {
    bar.set(true);
  }, 100);
});
```

That's where the fun begins. While this test is the very same code with a different name, and has exactly the same written logic, ***it fails because the computation tracking bar is never rerun***.

The `console.log` shows it very well:

> foo in its computation is: `false`
>   foo in its computation is: `true` *- reactivity kicked in!*
>   bar in its computation is: `false`
>   [Nothing]

While it is very clear that the computation for `foo` was rerun and thus its test was completed, the computation for `bar` is never invalidated and thus the test fails.

However this does not stop here. If we add a third test case for a new reactive variable (say, `baz`) and follow the same procedure as before (initializing it with the others, adding the test at the end in the same `describe` function) then it works perfectly!

```
var foo = new ReactiveVar(false),
    bar = new ReactiveVar(false),
    baz = new ReactiveVar(false);

it('should react to the changes of foo (1)', function(done) { /* ... */ });
it('should react to the changes of bar (2)', function(done) { /* ... */ });

it('should react to the changes of baz (3)', function(done) { /* ... */ });
```

Here test `(1)` succeeds, test `(2)` fails, test `(3)` succeeds.

Now if we add a fourth test, with a new `cat` for example, following the same procedure... Then test `(4)` will fail with the following log.

> foo in its computation is `false`
>   foo in its computation is `true`
>   bar in its computation is `false`  *bar is not rerun and fails*
>   baz in its computation is `false`
>   baz in its computation is `true`
>   cat in its computation is `false` *cat is not rerun and fails*
>   [Nothing]

`foo` and `baz` have been reacted unto, not `bar` and `cat`.

I have done it with two others (fifth and sixth), same result: `(5)` succeeds, `(6)` fails.
The "odd" tests succeed, the "even" ones fail.

Full reproduction code:

```
describe('Tracker usage with Jasmine', function() {
  var foo = new ReactiveVar(false),
      bar = new ReactiveVar(false),
      baz = new ReactiveVar(false),
      cat = new ReactiveVar(false),
      pup = new ReactiveVar(false),
      elf = new ReactiveVar(false);

  it('should react to the changes of foo (1)', function(done) {
    Tracker.autorun(function observeFoo(fooComputation) {
      var fooValue = foo.get();
      console.log('foo in its computation is', fooValue);
      if ( fooValue === true ) {
        fooComputation.stop();
        done();
      }
    });

    setTimeout(function setFoo() {
      foo.set(true);
    }, 100);
  });

  it('should react to the changes of bar (2)', function(done) {
    Tracker.autorun(function observeBar(barComputation) {
      var barValue = bar.get();
      console.log('bar in its computation is', barValue);
      if ( barValue === true ) {
        barComputation.stop();
        done();
      }
    });

    setTimeout(function setBar() {
      bar.set(true);
    }, 100);
  });

  it('should react to the changes of baz (3)', function(done) {
    Tracker.autorun(function observeBaz(bazComputation) {
      var bazValue = baz.get();
      console.log('baz in its computation is', bazValue);
      if ( bazValue === true ) {
        bazComputation.stop();
        done();
      }
    });

    setTimeout(function setBaz() {
      baz.set(true);
    }, 100);
  });

  it('should react to the changes of cat (4)', function(done) {
    Tracker.autorun(function observeCat(catComputation) {
      var catValue = cat.get();
      console.log('cat in its computation is', catValue);
      if ( catValue === true ) {
        catComputation.stop();
        done();
      }
    });

    setTimeout(function setCat() {
      cat.set(true);
    }, 100);
  });

  it('should react to the changes of pup (5)', function(done) {
    Tracker.autorun(function observePup(pupComputation) {
      var pupValue = pup.get();
      console.log('pup in its computation is', pupValue);
      if ( pupValue === true ) {
        pupComputation.stop();
        done();
      }
    });

    setTimeout(function setPup() {
      pup.set(true);
    }, 100);
  });

  it('should react to the changes of elf (6)', function(done) {
    Tracker.autorun(function observeElf(elfComputation) {
      var elfValue = elf.get();
      console.log('elf in its computation is', elfValue);
      if ( elfValue === true ) {
        elfComputation.stop();
        done();
      }
    });

    setTimeout(function setElf() {
      elf.set(true);
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

Why is this happening?
How can I solve this matter while keeping all these reactive variables in the same `describe` function?

---

I have tried to add nested `describe` functions without success.
This issue magically disappears when isolating the tests in their own non-related `describe` functions, please do not answer in such a way.

Comment: DEAR PEOPLE OF THE FUTURE: I solved this by switching over to `mike:mocha`. If you have to solve this using Jasmine... Good luck.